Stress concentration at the edges of tabs and slots
I am designing a fiberglass foam sandwich composite box that needs to hold to 20g's of acceleration. The box is going to be made of several flat pieces for ease of manufacturing, thus it is designed with a tab slot construction. When i run strength analyses the edges of the tabs and slots become stress concentration points. My first thought was to fillet the edges, but because the foam panels are going to be made on a 2 axis milling machine, filleting is not possible. Do any of you know how to solve this stress concentration issue? Below I've attached some photos of my FEA analyses. The green arrows indicate direction of force.




I thought milling rectangular holes with absolutely sharp corners is impossible. How do you manufacture these sharp edges?

There will always be stress concentration points at edges, that's inherent to the flow of stress around a hole. Your model seems to be impacted by a stress singularity, which is caused by the nature of FEM. Your corner is not going to be perfect, especially if it is cut on a milling machine, at some level, a fillet will always be there. If the stress at this point in the geometry is important, add a small fillet (perhaps the radius of the milling tool used) and refine the mesh to capture that fillet. If the stress is not important, just ignore the results there, the stress far from the corner should be correct.
